# How to update the current position of a point in manim? I want that the label of the point changing with the moving Point of the plot

Tags: python, plot, interactive, manim

"""Currently my Animation of the Points only show (x1|y1), (x2|y2) and (x3|y3) but how can i make it that the Points show the real position of of their corresponding points (even after i moved them). Thx for your time and answer"""

```
from manim import *
   import math


 class Test2(Scene):
    def construct(self):


    # Mobject

    plane = NumberPlane().add_coordinates()
    
    dot1 = Dot([2, 2, 0],radius=0.1 ,color=RED)
    dot2 = Dot([-2, 2, 0],radius=0.1, color=YELLOW)
    dot3 = Dot([0, -1, 0],radius=0.1, color=GREEN)

    dot1label = Text("(x1|y1)", font_size=25).next_to(dot1, RIGHT)
    dot2label = Text("(x2|y2)", font_size=25).next_to(dot2, RIGHT)
    dot3label = Text("(x3|y3)", font_size=25).next_to(dot3, RIGHT)
    labels = VGroup(dot1label, dot2label, dot3label)

    dot1label.add_updater(lambda x: x.next_to(dot1, DOWN + RIGHT))
    dot2label.add_updater(lambda x: x.next_to(dot2, DOWN + RIGHT))
    dot3label.add_updater(lambda x: x.next_to(dot3, DOWN + RIGHT))

    # script

    # 1S

    #self.play(Text2.animate.scale(0.5).shift([-4.9,3.3,0]))
    self.play(Create(plane))
    self.wait(0.5)
    self.play(Create(dot1), Create(dot2), Create(dot3))
    self.play(FadeIn(labels, shift=UP * 0.2))
    self.wait(1)
    self.play(dot1.animate.shift([-1,-3,0]))
    self.play(dot2.animate.shift([-1,-2,0]))
    self.play(dot3.animate.shift([3,1,0]))
    self.wait(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified one label for you:

```py
class Test2(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        # Mobject

        plane = NumberPlane().add_coordinates()
        
        dot1 = Dot([2, 2, 0],radius=0.1 ,color=RED)
        dot2 = Dot([-2, 2, 0],radius=0.1, color=YELLOW)
        dot3 = Dot([0, -1, 0],radius=0.1, color=GREEN)

        dot1label = always_redraw(lambda:
            Text("({:.1f}|{:.1f})".format(*plane.p2c(dot1.get_center())), font_size=25).next_to(dot1, DOWN+RIGHT)
        )
        dot2label = Text("(x2|y2)", font_size=25).next_to(dot2, RIGHT)
        dot3label = Text("(x3|y3)", font_size=25).next_to(dot3, RIGHT)
        labels = VGroup(dot1label, dot2label, dot3label)

        #dot1label.add_updater(lambda x: x.next_to(dot1, DOWN + RIGHT))
        dot2label.add_updater(lambda x: x.next_to(dot2, DOWN + RIGHT))
        dot3label.add_updater(lambda x: x.next_to(dot3, DOWN + RIGHT))

        # script

        # 1S

        #self.play(Text2.animate.scale(0.5).shift([-4.9,3.3,0]))
        self.play(Create(plane))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(Create(dot1), Create(dot2), Create(dot3))
        self.play(FadeIn(labels, shift=UP * 0.2))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(dot1.animate.shift([-1,-3,0]))
        self.play(dot2.animate.shift([-1,-2,0]))
        self.play(dot3.animate.shift([3,1,0]))
        self.wait(3)
```

[image: screenshot]